# Format a DATE with javascript (maybe regex)

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, date

I'm using JavaScript and JQuery and I've got a string like this (unchangeable xml response):

```
var str = "2017-01-08T16:06:52+00:00";
```

How can I convert to a Date like this:

```
08 january 2017, 16:06:52
```

Or at least:

```
08 01 2017, 16:06:52
```

I was trying to use a `.replace()` like:

```
str = str.replace(/(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})T(\d{8}).*/,'$2 $3 $1, $4');
```

But it doesn't works. :(

Comment: `new Date("2017-01-08T16:06:52+00:00").toLocaleString()` or maybe `new Date("2017-01-08T16:06:52+00:00").toGMTString().split(/\W/)` to get the fancy names without a list

Comment: @dandavis while much simpler, unfortunately that will use the date format specified on the client machine. If the OP requires that the date is always shown in the format they specified they will need to hand-code the formatting.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: i also showed how to use GMT to get the parts without a whitelist of names... with the parts array, custom formats are trivial.

Comment: I know, but it's still using the format of the client machine. The output of the above is an array of `Sun,,08,Jan,2017,16,06,52,GMT` which I suspect isn't what you intended either.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: i get the EXACT same parts because GMTString is standardized, unlike localeString... using the parts, one can make a custom format: something LIKE `p[1]+", " + p[3]+":" +p[5]+":"+p[2];` or whatever... just another option ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To do this you can create a `Date()` object from the string, then concatenate together a string from the methods the `Date()` object exposes. Try this:

```js
var str = "2017-01-08T16:06:52+00:00";
var date = new Date(str);
var months = [ "january", "february", "march", "april", "may", "june", "july", "august", "september", "october", "november", "december" ];

var dateString = ("00" + date.getDate()).slice(-2) + ' ' + months[date.getMonth()] + ' ' + date.getFullYear() + ', ' + ("00" + date.getHours()).slice(-2) + ':' + ("00" + date.getMinutes()).slice(-2) + ':' + ("00" + date.getSeconds()).slice(-2);

console.log(dateString);
```

Note that this can be made simpler by using a date formatting library (such as MomentJS or DateJS) however including an entire library to format a single date is rather wasteful. If you need to do this repeatedly throughout your site then they may be worth it.

Also note that in English speaking countries the month names should be capitalised, so consider amending the format for that case.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, if adding a library is an option you could use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/). You can [call `.format`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) and pass how you would like the output to be, for example:

```js
var str = "2017-01-08T16:06:52+00:00";
var momentDate = moment(str);

console.log(momentDate.format('DD MMMM YYYY HH:mm:ss'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.js"></script>
```

Comment: `moment(new Date())` produces the same result as `moment()` but is more to type. ;-) If using moment.js, it should use it for parsing too,and since the OP's string is in an ISO 8601 format  `moment(str)` will do the job.

Answer (score 0):

Your regular expression isn't quite right, `\d{8}` will match 8 consecutive digits but there are colons in there as well, you need something like:

```js
var str = "2017-01-08T16:06:52+00:00"
str = str.replace(/(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})T(.{8}).*/, '$2 $3 $1, $4');
console.log(str)
```

To replace the month number with the name is just a little more work:

```js
function reformatDate(s) {
  var months = [ "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" ];
  var b = s.split(/\D/);
  return b[2] + ' ' + months[b[1]-1] + ', ' + b[0] + ' ' + b[3] + ':' + b[4] + ':' + b[5];
}
  
  
var s = "2017-01-08T16:06:52+00:00"  
console.log(reformatDate(s));
```

Be careful using the Date constructor (and Date.parse) for parsing strings, it's largely implementation dependent.

If you want to present the date and time in the timezone of the client, then parse the string to a Date, then return it as a string. A library like [*fecha.js*](https://github.com/taylorhakes/fecha) is good for that. It's small and just does parsing and formatting, e.g.

```
var s = '2017-01-08T16:06:52+00:00'
var d = fecha.parse(s,'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZZ');

console.log(fecha.format(d,'dd MMMM, YYYY HH:mm:ss'));
```